# Should list items be on separate pages, or all together on the same page?

Tags: gui-design

I am writing a Windows program that downloads jokes from a website and presents them to the user. Currently, the jokes are displayed all together on a bulleted list. I've been told that the design is not practical and its been suggested to make the jokes displayed in pages with navigation buttons like a 3rd-party app shown below. The stated advantage is that it tires the eye less.

This is the design of the 3rd-party app:

[image: Their app screenshot]

And this is the design of my app:

[image: My app screenshot]

I countered by saying that my app's design needs no button pressing (only scrolling) and that it makes use all the available screen (the app in the first picture particularly, when used on a tablet and there is a big joke does not use all the screen for this one joke).

Comment: Could you post the other option screenshot? As a side comment I would not  put the navigation buttons over the ads, it looks like it is advertisement too.

Comment: OK. I posted it. And I did not make the app in the first picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that scrolling should be fine (up to a point - maybe a maximum of 10 or 20 jokes per page?). But I think the bullet points are not sufficiently distinct, since many jokes have dashes included in the body. So, when scanning the jokes, it's hard to clearly see where each joke begins. I would suggest finding an alternative list style that makes it easier to see where each joke begins. For example: could you alternate between a white and light gray background? (jokes 1, 3, 5 have a white background, jokes 2, 4, 6 have a gray background). Or maybe insert a horizontal line between jokes, or enclose every joke in a box, or alternate fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of jokes using the [listview component](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

Users will read the Jokes that end in two lines on the same screen or they can even tap on it to see if there is more.

Show the three dots (...) at the end of second line for jokes that have more than two lines of content so the user understands that there is more to read, and taps on it.

After a tap on each row navigate the user to a independent screen where the user can read complete joke.

Provide a back button option to naviate back to the main/dashboard screen.

[image]